# K-means using only specific dataframe columns with scikit-learn

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, k-means

I'm using the `k-means` algorithm from the `scikit-learn` library, and the values I want to cluster are in a pandas dataframe with 3 columns: `ID`, `value_1` and `value_2`.

I want to cluster the information using `value_1` and `value_2`, but I also want to keep the `ID` associated with it (so I can create a list of `ID`s in each cluster).

What's the best way of doing this? Currently it clusters using the `ID` number as well and that's not the intention.

My current code (`X` is the pandas dataframe):

```
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=2, n_init=3, max_iter=3000, random_state=1)
(X_train, X_test) = train_test_split(X[['value_1','value_2']],test_size=0.30)
kmeans = kmeans.fit(X_train)
```

Comment: Why not creating another dataframe with kmeans and adding the value_3 column?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Do the clustering using only the columns of interest (as in your example). Then add the list of labels `kmeans.labels_` as another column to `X_train` (or `X_test`). The labels are in the same order as the original rows.

```
# A toy DF
X = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1,2,3,4,5],
                  'value_1': [1,3,1,4,5],
                  'value_2': [0,0,1,5,0]})

# Split ALL columns
(X_train, X_test) = train_test_split(X,test_size=0.30)
# Cluster using SOME columns
kmeans = kmeans.fit(X_train[['value_1','value_2']])
# Save the labels
X_train.loc[:,'labels'] = kmeans.labels_
```

Since both `X_train` and `X_tests` are slices of `X`, you may see a warning here:

> A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.

You can ignore it.

```
X_train
#   id  value_1  value_2  labels
#4   5        5        0       0
#0   1        1        0       0
#3   4        4        5       1
```

Comment: All good in the question (+1) and the answer (+1) from a coding perspective; however, normally for kmeans (or for clustering in general) we don't split to training & test subsets...

Comment: I'm aware, we're sort of using k-means in all the wrong ways in my project - but it's intentional

Comment: .loc[] will give a warning on recent pandas versions. X_train = X_train.assign(labels=kmeans.labels_) would be better.